# Question arose from Rudin 9.21

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Theorem:
Suppose f maps an open set $E \subset R^n$ into $R^m$. Then $f \in \mathcal{C'}(E)$(continuously diff. on E) if the partial derivatives $D_j f_i$ exist and are continuous on E for $1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n$.

PF)
by definition,
$||f'(x)-f'(y)|| = sup_{u_1^2+...+u_n^2\leq1}|Fu|$

where we denote by $F = f'(x)-f'(y)$
, $u = u_1e_1+...+u_ne_n$ and $e_i$ s' are standard units of $R^n$.
Then:
$Fu = \sum_{i,j}{u_jD_{ji}e'_i}$
where we denote by $D_{ji}=D_jf_i(x)-D_jf_i(y)$, and $e'_i$s' are standard units of $R^m$.
fix x, since $D_jf_i$ s' are continuous, we can find $\delta$ sufficiently small so that:
$|x-y|\leq\delta\implies |D_{ji}|\leq\epsilon$ for arbitrary choice of i,j,$\epsilon$.
Hence:
$|Fu|\leq \epsilon|\sum_{i,j}{u_je'_i}|$
Which suggests that:
$f'(y)$ converges to $f'(x)$ within metric space $(L(R^n,R^m),||-||)$ as y in E moves to x.
i.e: f is continuously differentiable in E.

I think this suffices, then why would author give whole different proof for readers? I'll insert the proof in the book if necessary, for that case I must  have gone wrong way.